# Sharing data between viewpagers

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragmentstatepageradapter

I created two ViewPagers in my activity and what I'm trying to do is to share the same data between them.

The ViewPager 1 shows a fragment for every string in a list named "A". 
Every fragment has a simple layout with a TextView.

The ViewPager 2 shows a fragment for every string from the same list "A". 
Every fragment has a simple layout with an EditText.

I'm trying to obtain this behavior:

1) VP 1 is visible and the user can swipe every fragment populated with the strings from the list "A".

2) VP 2 is invisible.

3) After the onClick event on the TextView, I'd like to hide VP 1 and show VP 2 with the same string content but in an EditText instead of TextView.

4) The user can modify the content of the EditText.

5) After 4) the user can press a button in the toolbar and come back to VP 1 with the content updated.

I'm using the FragmentStatePagerAdapter.

I was thinking to save data directly in a DB or in a file.

Is it possible to create something like that?
How can I implement the event that after tapping on fragment "n" in VP1 reaching the fragment "n" in VP2?
How can I update the content in VP 1 after the mod in VP 2?

The code at the moment is quite simple so I didn't post it here, by the way is very similar to [this one](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentStatePagerAdapter.html).

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use one `ViewPager`, with the fragment having a `TextView` and an `EditText`. The `EditText`'s visibility is set to "GONE". On click of the `TextView` set it's visibility to "GONE" and the `EditText`'s to "VISIBLE". When the toolbar button is clicked do the opposite and also populate the new text to the appropriate `TextView`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Drilon, I'll try your solution that is very simple, but probably the best. I'll let you know.

Answer (score 0):

The Object-Oriented approach is using an interface. You can create an interface in your activity for the fragments to communicate with.

ViewPagerComm.class:

```
public interface ViewPagerComm {
String getData();
void setData(String data);
}
```

Activity:

```
public class FragmentStatePagerSupport extends Activity, implements     ViewPagerComm {

String data;
...

@Override
public void setData(String data){
this.data = data;
}

@Override
public String getData(){
return data;
}

}

...
}
```

In the adapter:

```
public static class MyAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    ViewPagerComm callback;
    public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm, ViewPagerComm callback) {
        this.callback = callback;
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return NUM_ITEMS;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return ArrayListFragment.newInstance(position, callback);
    }
}
```

In your Fragments:

```
public static class ArrayListFragment extends ListFragment {
    ViewPagerComm callback;

    static ArrayListFragment newInstance(int num, ViewPagerComm callback) {
        ArrayListFragment f = new ArrayListFragment();
        f.callback = callback;
        // Supply num input as an argument.
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt("num", num);
        f.setArguments(args);

        return f;
    }

}
```

Now, whenever a fragment calls setData(aString) the parent activity will hold the data. Whenever a fragment calls getData(), the data will be retrieved from the activity.

Comment: Instead of using the interface, I'm using EventBus, but I think this isn't the point. I don't have any problem to communicate between Fragment/Activity in VP1 or VP2, the problem is that I have no idea how to switch from fragment N in VP1 to fragment N in VP2.

Comment: ok, eventbus is good. I don't quite understand your problem. If you want to communicate between two ViewPagers, then send an event to the bus using one, and implement it in the activity to set the second one.

Answer (score 0):

Just declare Variable in your Activity (your Viewpager Activity)

```
public class TestActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
     public String test;
}
```

And access it in your Fragment (within code)

```
((TestActivity)getActivity()).test
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Simon, but I don't understand your solution. 
Could you provide a better explanation?

Comment: You have your Activity, called however, in this case it is TestActivity. After opening the bracket { you could declare variables in Class scope. The variable is accessible from other classes by setting it public.

Now in your fragments you could access this variable with ((TestActivity)getActivity()).VARIABLE

Just go to your fragment where text is edited and set String normally ((TestActivity)getActivity()).test="ABC"

Then go to your fragment where text should be displayed and then access this: ((TestActivity)getActivity()).test